# Default uTorrent upload limits?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I am using uTorrent for my torrents and when I open a new torrent with utorrent, I must manually

1. right click the item
2. click on bandwidth allocation
3. set it to **HIGH**

then I must repat the first 2 steps again and then go to click on **Set upload limit** and click the proper desired amount which for me is **1 Kb/s**

This is very annoying to do this on every single torrent, is there a way to have these set as the default values in utorrent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must set a low upload speed (a very bad idea), you can set the global upload limit in Options > Preferences > Network.

Answer (score 3):

1. Bandwidth allocation is a relative thing, setting a single torrent on high does nothing.
2. Setting the upload limit to 1kb/s is going **completely against the very concept of bittorrent**, and every client out there will punish you for it. A peer that's uploading to you has a higher weighting, and as such you're more likely to upload to them - this works both ways. By basically refusing to share, and treating torrents like a direct download, you're **seriously slowing down your own speeds**. put it up to something fairer, (I use 60kb/s, any higher and my net starts to choke), and always seed to at least a 1:1 ratio, just out of common decency.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I never thought of that but regardless it would be nice to be able to set your own default value even if I wanted the default to be 60kb/s

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but you could just set the global upload limit to something low like 5 Kb/s

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to globally limit upload speeds is to right click the tray icon and select a value under the 'Upload Limit' sub-menu.

Answer (score -1):

1Kb/s is not high. Hence why you have to change it manually after setting your upload limits to high...

Comment: How does this provide a solution to the question?